# how to handle uiscroll view with uistackview inside in it . iOS 9 auto layout with storyboard

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-autolayout

[image]I have added my UISTACKview inside UISCROLLview , now how can we handle uistackview content positions. so user can view proper form.

Comment: I suggest to use table view instead of scrollview.

Comment: I was trying stack view it manages all the fields :) table view is good option